# Splitting variable into two groups

Tags: r

I am trying to split a numeric variable (Age) within the AdultUCI dataset into two groups.  One that is <50 and one that is >=50.  I cannot get past how to do this. I have tried a number of different things, but all of the code returns an error message.

`adult[1:2,]

adult[[ "age"]] <- ordered(cut(adult[[ "age"]], c(5,25,45,65,100)), 
                              labels = c("<50", ">=50"))`

Comment: There are several ways to do this in R. Try using `ifelse()`. First, check class of your variable to make sure it is numeric (i.e., `class(adult$age)`. If it is not numeric you'll need to convert it. Then you can use `if else`: something like `adult$age <- if else(adult$age < 50, 0, 1)`. Assuming `adult` is the name of your dataframe.

Comment: Also, thanks for posting what you attempted! In the future, you'll get more helpful responses if you also post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your desired output. Good luck ,and follow-up if you have more questions.

Comment: Couple of items, you should not assign the cut values to the same column you are trying to divide.  In your cut statement you are defining 5 cut points but only 2 labels.  Your beaks should be c(0, 50, 100).

Comment: That worked! thank you Andrew.  You were correct, the "age" age variable was listed as an integer, so I used the following to create the object "Age" as a numeric value.

#then ran the code provided 
>adult$age <- ifelse(adult$age < 50, 0, 1)

>Age <- as.numeric(adult$age)